# I have two MicroSD cards that no longer work in my Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, sd-card, noobs

I have two different sized SD cards that both worked in my Raspberry Pi. I was trying to set up OwnCloud but I just wanted to completely restart so I shut down the Pi and took the MicroSD card out. I formatted it to FAT and extracted NOOBS onto it. (Keep in mind the Pi the first time I put in the Pi). It is really weird because I am able to use the cards in everything (NVidia Shield, two cameras, and my computer) but the RPi will not boot from them. Do SD cards work more than once in a RPi?

So on two seperate occassions, SD Cards no longer work with the Pi. The same thing happened both times. 1. I had installed NOOBS and it booted where I installed Raspbian and tried to set something up. Then I got frustrated and wanted to try again so I took the card out and formatted it then reinstalled NOOBS but the Pi would not boot from it. Both SD Cards work perfectly in everything else except the Pi.

I've only found one other thread where someone has had a [similar problem.](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/21337/l/sd-card-not-working-any-more?displayFullThread=true)

I have just ordered a new card off Amazon that will arrive tomorrow and I assume it will work fine unless I reformat it after using it in the Pi once.

I'd be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: Unless you tell us how "I formatted it to FAT" any answer is speculation (I have my suspicions). Why are you using `NOOBS` - the only justification is that it is supposed to be easier? I suggest you use a Raspbian image, and follow the Foundation guidelines for whatever machine you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention where you formatted the card. I have seen issues where foramtting on a mac created issue. You may want to format using a windows machine. Also there are several tool which can help you to format/extract and update the card. I would strongly suggest using one of those instead of doing it manually. Check out the installation page of [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)

Comment: Thanks! I installed Raspbian Jessie Lite and it booted fine.